# How to assign values to variables directly through a method instead of through an instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

The standard way to compute areas of rectangles using 'class' in Python3 is via something like the following

```
 class Rectangles:
     def __init__(self,length,width):
         self.a = length
         self.b = width

    def Area(self):
         return self.a*self.b
  example = Rectangles(2,3)
  print('Area of the specific example=',example.Area())
```

Obviously, the above code will generate a print of the answer to be equal to 6.

My question: How to hold up the assignment of length=2 and width=3 up until the very last line. In other words, I would like to avoid ''pre-defining'' that example with fixed length and width, so that I could assign length and width directly to Area(), which would lead to direct calculation of areas. Following is my tentative approach (the following code only shows my intention and it doesn't work in Python, and that's why I am wondering about a way to make it work...)

```
  class Rectangles:
     def __init__(self,length,width):
         self.a = length
         self.b = width

     def Area(self,length,width): ##I intend to assign values to length and width DIRECTLY in the method Area() 
         return self.a*self.b

  example =Rectangles() ##I would NOT like to assign length and width too early at this stage. How to correctly express that??
  example.Area(2,3) ##Inside Area() is where I WOULD like to assign a length and width to example.Area(4,7) ##In this way I don't need to define a fixed example for each given (length, width)
```

In this way, I don't have to define a bunch of fixed instances (say, example (4,7), example (2,3), etc...) for computing their areas. Could anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then, what you want is just a function, there's no need to have a class...

Comment: That's already defined, in fact, as `from operator import mul`.

Comment: If you don't need any internal state, you could just use a function. or, you `.area` method could take the values as arguments.. although that doesn't make much sense. Why must this rectangle be a class if you don't need any internal state?

Comment: Yes I understand the function would work easily and perfectly for my purpose. But is there really no way to make the class approach work? I am doing it as an exercise for the class approach.

Comment: jonrsharpe: Could you elaborate on how it works for my intention?

Comment: You can, but the lesson you should learn is that you don't need a class.

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you would need an object-oriented approach here. If you wanted to have an area function organized under `Rectangles`, use a static method:

```
class Rectangles:
    @staticmethod
    def Area(length, width):
        return length * width

example = Rectangles()
example.Area(2,3) 
example.Area(4,7)
# OR
Rectangles.Area(2,3) 
Rectangles.Area(4,7)
```

I'm not sure why you would need this, though.

Comment: Thanks, iz_. I just have got a related quick question: How about if I  fix length = 2 in all rectangles? Is there a way to let ''example=Rectangles(2)'' so an ''example.Area(3)'' would involve just the width?

Comment: @user31899 What you want is possible, but will lead to ugly code. You shouldn't be able to use `Area` as both an instance and a static function. I suggest refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to instantiate a `Rectangle` without providing the params you can define default values in the class constructor:

```
 class Rectangles:
     def __init__(self, length=0, width=0):
         self.a = length
         self.b = width
```

And to define the `length` and `width` values through the `Area()` method, just add them as parameters:

```
     def Area(self, length, width):
         self.a = length
         self.b = width
         return self.a*self.b
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **'tentative approach'** is not going to work. You have provided two parameters to the initialization method `__init__()` of your `Rectangles` class but when you're creating instances, you're not providing those 2 required positional arguments: 'length' and 'width'. This will throw an error.

I think you are trying to have something like the following code.

**Code**

```py
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self):
      pass # Left blank for future use

    @staticmethod
    def area(self, length, width):
      return length*width

example =Rectangle() 
example.area(2,3) 
example.area(4,7)
```